# fullscreen Videoplayer with self hiding controls

Tags: android

I want to add a video player feature in my app to play MP4 files from my server and maybe also videos hosted on Youtube.

Videos would be played in fullscreen mode only, with controls on overlay (like the Youtube app), and also gestures.

I referred to an example from Android documentation and found exactly what I need the Video Player example (Views/System UI Visibility/Video Player). Unfortunately it uses the ActionBar and new SYSTEM_UI flags to hide+fullscreen and show controls and manage action bar transparency.

I want my app compatible with Gingerbread systems so I can't start from this example.

Do you know how I can simulate the Video Player UI style of the example (or the ICS Youtube app which is the same)?

Is it as "simple" as stacking views over a videoView?

Comment: Many Views have visability as property.You also may consider FrameLayout. You can hide them somehow.

Comment: You may want to have a loot at ActionBarSherlock that allows you to use the ActionBar with older versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

It is that simple.

I did use my VideoView as the lowest layer (first entry in xml) and put several other layers on top of it. 
However the video does not cause onDraw calls on the upper layers so you need to do that urself to make sure they are drawn.